# How to get CXMLElement when using xpath

Tags: objective-c, touchxml

Is there a way to get a `CXMLElement` back when xpath querying a document? The `XCMLNode` item returned by the `- (NSArray *)nodesForXPath:(NSString *)xpath error:(NSError **)error;` doesn't contain the attributes functions.

Is there a way to either directly get an element or convert the node to an element?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast it, but be sure to check the type first:

```
for (CXMLNode *node in nodeArray)
{
    if ([node kind] == CXMLElementKind)
    {
        CXMLElement *element = (CXMLElement *)node;

        // do stuff with element
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR CXMLElement is a subclass of the CXMLNode. If you are sure that the xpath will return CXMLElements, then just cast CXMLNode to CXMLElement. In other case you should check node type and then cast.

From touchXML documention:

```
NSArray *nodes = NULL;
//  searching for piglet nodes
nodes = [doc nodesForXPath:@"//piglet" error:nil];

for (CXMLElement *node in nodes) {
...
}
```

Comment: I actually looked a the source, and the CXMLNode is created in the function itself, so it's not a CXMLElement...

Comment: https://github.com/schwa/TouchXML/blob/master/Documentation/TouchXMLParsing.markdown